# How to print and calculate a value in Python that is inside a Json in MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have this Json inside mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aba203f00435837802f9c49"),
"AED" : 4.572098,
"AFN" : 86.093419,
"ALL" : 130.478529,
"AMD" : 597.524404,
"ANG" : 2.216574,
"AOA" : 264.413246,
}
```

And this in Python

```
import pymongo
uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client= pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['countries_db']
collection = database['currency']

currency =[AED['AED'] for AED in collection.find({})]
res=currency*2
print(res)
```

**Output:
[4.572098, 4.572098]**

And when I print this, It comes as a string value, It repeats AED two times.
Is there any way to call the value as float and calculate it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's returning a string value; it's returning a list. When you try to multiply a list, it'll just duplicate itself that many times, which is what you're seeing here. How you resolve it depends on how many elements you expect to get back from the `find()` operation as well as what you'd like to do with them all.

1. If you're expecting 1 element as a result of the `find()` operation, you should turn that into a `find_one()`, which will return a float, making your multiplication operation work as expected with the following code:

   ```
   item = collection.find_one({})  # Returns a single doc. Note the lack of square brackets
   currency = item['AED']  # Get the desired key of the document
   res = currency * 2
   ```
2. If you're expecting more than 1 element, you can multiple each returned value by 2 by running a map on it with `res = map(lambda x: x*2, currency)`

Comment: I just have to import one element, it didn't work, I want the element that is inside the object, do I have to import the object in Mongo?

Comment: See the changes to my response. You still needed to remove the square brackets wrapping the call, which was creating a list (in addition to the call to find(), which was also returning a list).